# Remove-Item : Only removing filetypes, keeping folder structure intact

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete "only" specific filetypes in a folder and all sub-folders, but keeping all sub-folders intact.

i'm a bit of a novice, but I figured both of these were correct, but they spit out errors instead:

```
get-childitem $sourceDir -exclude .dll,.lib -recurse | remove-item
```

Fails with this error: remove-item : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt

This one:

```
#Remove-Item $sourceDir -recurse -exclude .dll,.lib | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Simply does nothing.

Comment: What is the version of the PS that you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for PS V2:

```
$excluded = @("*.dll", "*.lib")
get-childitem -path $sourceDir -exclude $excluded -Recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Or this for V3

```
$excluded = @("*.dll", "*.lib")
get-childitem -path $sourceDir -File -exclude $excluded -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same error:


`Remove-Item : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.

get-childitem -path $sourceDir -exclude $excluded -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + 
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-Item], PSInvalidOp
erationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand`

Comment: You will need to add the -File switch parameter and potentially the -Confirm:$false switch to the Get-ChildItem statement above... so 

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Exclude $excluded -Recurse -File | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm:$false

Comment: @Staeton Grey - d3r3kk is right you need to specify -File switch if you run PS v3 or above, if you run PS v2 pipe to  where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }. I have updated my post

Comment: Success! the -file switch has fixed the problem. Thanks very much guys.
It's a shame there's so much difference in each version of PS.. can't find any information about the -file switch on MSDN.